# How does the for loop run in such a case?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, static

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(){
        
    static int val=11;
    return --val;
}

int main()
{
   for( f1(); f1(); f1()){
        printf("%d",f1());
   }
}
```

The output of the program is :
`8 5 2`

Could someone explain me what does `for(f1();f1();f1())` do?

Comment: Your question is missing information: What did you expect to happen? How does your expectation differ from the output you got? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easier understanding I'll talk about functions as such:

```
for (A(); B(); C()) {
    printf("%d", D());
}
```

So understand that all A B C and D are calls to f1() but I want to be able to differentiate them.

1st thing to understand is how are the "parameters" of `for` working.

- 1st one is the init part, it will be executed once only, before the evaluation of the first condition.
- 2nd one is the condition part, it will be executed before every loop, to check if it needs to keep looping or stop.
- 3rd one is the conclusion part, it will be executed after every loop, before the next evaluation of the condition.

We can then understand that your program will execute in this order:

- call A() to initialize the for loop => val = 10;
- call B() to check condition => val = 9
- call D() in  your printf => val = 8 *gets printed*
- call C() to end an iteration => val = 7
- call B() to check condition => val = 6
- call D() in  your printf => val = 5 *gets printed*
- call C() to end an iteration => val = 4
- call B() to check condition => val = 3
- call D() in  your printf => val = 2 *gets printed*
- call C() to end an iteration => val = 1
- call B() to check condition => val = 0 *condition ends*

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void) {
    static int val = 11;
    return --val;
}

int main(void) {
    int (*f1)(void) = foo; //4 function pointers to the same function
    int (*f2)(void) = foo;
    int (*f3)(void) = foo;
    int (*f4)(void) = foo;

    for (f1(); f2(); f3()) {
        printf("%d", f4());
    }
}
```

The execution goes like this

```
               val = 11
f1()            10
f2()             9 "true"
f4()       print 8
f3()             7
f2()             6 "true"
f4()       print 5
f3()             4
f2()             3 "true"
f4()       print 2
f3()             1
f2()             0 "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

The C for loop contains 3 items:

- the initialisation
- the condition
- the incrementation

A for loop run until the condition is equal to either 0 or null.

You enter the loop, it call `f1()` a first time in the initialisation so val equal 10

At each iteration, it will call `f1()` three time, to check the condition, to do the increment part and in the printf call. Thus at each iteration we have `val = val - 3`

Once `val == 0` you exit the loop.

Note that it only work because `val` is static thus not being reinitialised at each call of `f1()`